# 'WhereIterable<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'

Tags: dictionary, dart, exception

Someone please help... I am going mad with this!

if I have:

```
void main() {
  List<Map> people = [];

  people.add({'name': 'Patrick', 'age': 56});
  people.add({'name': 'Jeannette', 'age': 55});

  print(people.where((person) => person['name'] == 'Patrick'));
}
```

as expected the output is:
({name: Patrick, age: 56})

but if I put the where in a class, like this:

```
class People {
  List<Map> people = [];

  void add(Map data) {
    people.add(data);
  }

  List<Map> get filtered {
    return people.where((m) => m['name'] == 'Patrick');
  }
}

void main() {
  People people = People();

  people.add({'name': 'Patrick', 'age': 56});
  people.add({'name': 'Jeannette', 'age': 55});

  print(people.filtered);
}
```

I get:
Unhandled exception:
type 'WhereIterable<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'
#0      People.filtered (file:///C:/flutter/apps/mapDB/scratch.dart:9:5)
#1      main (file:///C:/flutter/apps/mapDB/scratch.dart:19:16)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

Comment: `people.where(...)` returns an `Iterable`, but your `filtered` getter is declared to return a `List`.  Either change the getter to return an `Iterable` instead or explicitly create a `List` from the `Iterable` by using `people.where(...).toList()`.

Comment: Thanks James. Sorted now 